# Pandas DataFrame Add column to index without resetting

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas

how do I add `'d'` to the index below without having to reset it first?

```
from pandas import DataFrame
df = DataFrame( {'a': range(6), 'b': range(6), 'c': range(6)} )
df.set_index(['a','b'], inplace=True)
df['d'] = range(6)

# how do I set index to 'a b d' without having to reset it first?
df.reset_index(['a','b','d'], inplace=True)
df.set_index(['a','b','d'], inplace=True)

df
```

Answer (score 131, accepted):

We added an `append` option to `set_index`. Try that.

The command is:

```
df.set_index(['d'], append=True)
```

(we don't need to specify ['a', 'b'], as they already are in the index and we're appending to them)

Comment: Is there a way append the other indexes? Having the new index as the first index rather than the last one.

Comment: pro-tip, don't forget `inplace=True` if you're not storing the result

Answer (score -2):

Your code is not valid, reset_index has no inplace argument in my version of pandas (0.8.1). 
The following achieves what you want but there's probably a more elegant way, but you've not provided enough information as to why you are avoiding the reset_index.

```
df2.index = MultiIndex.from_tuples([(x,y,df2['d'].values[i]) for i,(x,y) in enumerate(df2.index.values)])
```

HTH